# "associated type ... must be specified", but isn't used

Tags: rust, associated-types, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects

Why is the associated type required here, even though it's never used?

```
trait Tr {
    type Ty;
    fn go(&self) -> () {}
}

fn foo(t: dyn Tr) -> () {
    t.go()
}
```

I get

```
2 |   type Ty;   
  |   -------- `Ty` defined here   
...  
6 | fn foo(t: dyn Tr) -> () {  
  |           ^^^^^^ associated type `Ty` must be specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a trait object, and it is a requirement for trait objects that all associated types are specified. Your case is very simple and the methods of the trait do not use the associated type, but the [object safety rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects) are designed for the more general case.

If you were just using a type parameter, bound by `Tr`, you wouldn't need to specify the associated type:

```
fn foo<T: Tr>(t: T) -> () {
    t.go()
}
```

That's because the associated type can be inferred for each `T` that you call `foo` with.

If trait objects were allowed to have an unspecified  associated type then code inside the function would not be able to infer it. You *could* argue in this case, that this should just limit what the function is allowed to do, but the object safety rules are given for the definition of a trait object type, regardless of how it is actually used. This makes is simpler to think about because there aren't some situations where a trait object can be used and others where it can't.

---

As an aside, even if you specified the associated types for the object in your function signature, you would have to pass the object by reference or boxed, e.g.:

```
fn foo(t: &dyn Tr<Ty = SomeType>) -> () {
    t.go()
}
```

That's because trait objects do not have a size known at compile-time. Instead you need to put them behind a reference, which *does* have a known size.